Can community cards be used as a hand?
There is already a staight from the community cards that are on the table, its 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9. First player has a 4 and 2, making another straight. And the second player has pair of kings. Who wins? Does in this case the high card kick in because of the first player straight is lower that community cards straight? And in that case does it mean that if player one had a 10 instead of a 4, he gets to win the round?

In Texas hold ’em, the best combination of 5 cards out of all 7 cards (the 2 private cards + the 5 community cards) wins.
A list of all the hands you mentioned, sorted by rank (strongest hand first) follows.

T 9 8 7 6 (ten-high straight)
9 8 7 6 5 (nine-high straight)
7 6 5 4 3 (seven-high straight; assuming the first player has 4 & 3 instead of 4 & 2 like you mentioned)
K K 9 8 7 (pair of kings)
9 8 7 4 3 (nine high)

The best combination of 5 cards on the board you mentioned is the nine-high straight. It makes the players’ private cards irrelevant (because any combination of 5 cards made with the pair of kings or the 4 & 3 is worse than what’s currently on the board), so both players win the hand, and the pot is shared between the two players.
A player holding a ten would have won the pot because the best combination, a ten-high straight, would have been better than a nine-high straight, yes.

Can the people who downvoted my answer tell me what is wrong with it? Thank you.
